# Change the JButton's shape

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, shapes

I'm making the game Master Mind, I've filled my matrix up with JButtons so people can click them to change the color.

Now I want to change the shape of my rectangular buttons to circles, is there a way I can change them all at once since I worked with a loop to create all them.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some methods that have to be overwritten to edit the shape of a component. (Including sample code)

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
      g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    } else {
      g.setColor(getBackground());
    }
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);

    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

  protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,     getSize().height-1);
  }

  Shape shape;
  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    if (shape == null || 
      !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
      shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    return shape.contains(x, y);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search Google for a tutorial about this.

This is an easy tutorial: [How to change the shape of a JButton](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/207123-change-the-shape-of-jbutton/)

Comment: Beware that [link-only answers tend to be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)